# Excel Conditional Formatting - Highlight row with the next date from TODAY

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a number of dates throughout the year that have 3 weeks gaps between them. im looking to highlight the past dates in red and only the next date in amber.

[image]

Comment: Do you only want the "Next Day" (i.e. Today is 04/3/2019, Next Day = 05/3/2019)? Or do you want any day that is greater than today plus 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dates are in `A1:A8` (adjust ranges as necessary), you could create two rules based on the following formulas:

1. Past dates (red): `=AND(A1<TODAY(),A1<>"")`
2. Next date (amber): `=AND(A1<>"",A1>=TODAY(),COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$8,"<"&A1,$A$1:$A$8,">="&TODAY())=0)`

[image]

The `A1<>""` is included to ignore blank cells.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different solution, that I believe is very straight forward and doesn't require multiple statements.

Old Dates (if no "Next Day" dates are found, then nothing will change colors) = `=A1TODAY(),$A$1:$A$8))``

Old Dates (including Today) Formula (This code will change colors regardless)= `$A1=AND($A1<=TODAY(),$A1<>"")` - Similar to BigBen (Difference is that I include `Today()`).

Next day Formula = `=A1=MIN(IF($A$1:$A$8>TODAY(),$A$1:$A$8))`

Everyday after today (just in case)= `=A1>=MIN(IF($A$1:$A$8>TODAY(),$A$1:$A$8))`

Note that if you decide to use these formula's within cells you must use "Ctrl + Shift + Enter" as this is an array formula.

[image]

Comment: Very nice. I think there's a typo in the last formula: `>=` instead of `=>`. Though if all the dates are less than today, I don't think the red shading would work.

Comment: @BigBen, Thanks for pointing out the problem with my "Red" Shading area. You are correct. If you do not have a date that is found with the formula, then nothing will change to Red.

Personally, I think this gives another extra advantage when looking through information. (i.e. if no new dates are found, then conditional formatting stops working)...I have updated my code above to reflect a simple solution (similar to yours), but I have also left my OG code.